# k-NN and some questions about k values and decision boundary

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor, pattern-recognition, knn

I ran into some facts make me confusing.

For k-NN classifier:

> I) why classification accuracy is not better with large values of k.
>
> II) the decision boundary is not smoother with smaller value of k.
>
> III) why decision boundary is not linear?
>
> IV) why k-NN need not explicitly training step?

any example or idea would be highly appreciated me to learn me about this fact in short, or why these are true?

Answer (score 3):

> I) why classification accuracy is not better with large values of k.

Because the idea of kNN is that an unseen data instance will have the same label (or similar label in case of regression) as its closest neighbors. If you take a lot of neighbors, you will take neighbors that are far apart for large values of `k`, which are irrelevant.

For example, consider that you want to tell if someone lives in a house or an apartment building and the correct answer is that they live in a house. If you take a small `k`, you will look at buildings close to that person, which are likely also houses. If you take a large `k`, you'll also consider buildings outside of the neighborhood, which can also be skyscrapers.

There is a variant of kNN that considers **all** instances / neighbors, no matter how far away, but that weighs the more distanced ones less. This is called **distance weighted knn**.

> II) the decision boundary is not smoother with smaller value of k.

Why is a polygon with smaller number of vertices usually not smoother than one with a large number of vertices? Considering more neighbors can help smoothen the decision boundary because it might cause more points to be classified similarly, but it also depends on your data.

> III) why decision boundary is not linear?

Because the distance function used to find the `k` nearest neighbors is not linear, so it usually won't lead to a linear decision boundary.

> IV) why k-NN need not explicitly training step?

Because there is nothing to train. kNN does not build a model of your data, it simply assumes that instances that are close together in space are similar. You don't need any training for this, since the position of the instances in space are what you are given as input.

Comment: would you please provide a short numerical example with points to better understand ?

Comment: @AliMovagher I don't have time to come up with original examples right now, but the wikipedia entry for knn has some, and you can find more on google.

Comment: what do you mean by Considering more neighbors can help smoothen the decision boundary because it might cause more points to be classified similarly?

Comment: @AliMovagher - If `k == number of points - 1`, then all points will be classified as the class that appears more often, leading to a completely smooth decision surface (because the decision surface is basically the whole plane). This is likely to happen for values smaller than `number of points - 1` as well. http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/98820 you can play around with it here to see it.